# "Ставить укол" — можно ли так говорить и писать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Ставить укол" — можно ли так говорить и писать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл такую информацию:
Укол (или инъекцию) только делают. «Поставить» его можно только в мире профессионального жаргона медиков. Лингвисты говорят, что можно употреблять и глагол «ставить», и глагол «делать». Но стилистически нейтральный и общеупотребительный вариант (а значит, литературный) один: «делать укол, прививку». Выражение «ставить прививку» приемлемо разве что в профессиональной речи врачей.
https://mel.fm/gramotnost/gramotny-otvet/5139642-vaccination

То есть существующий вариант (допустимый), но не литературный, до него не дотягивает.
Чем популярнее выражение, тем оно грамотнее. Так устроены языки.
Оно проходит такой путь: *никто так не скажет (ноль) => некорректно, но такое уже можно услышать => разговорно (допустимо) => литературно (образцово)*.
Эта фраза ближе к разговорному стилю, но пытается дорасти до литературного.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138902/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd---------).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец *Для меня не звучат вторые в контексте вашего ответа* — да, "совсем" и "очень" не подходят, потому что мы не знаем, чего именно ему хватает (чтобы дотянуться). Нет конкретики. Разбираться с незвучанием — моё любимое.